# Passing an arbitrary function as a parameter in Go

Tags: go, decorator, function-pointers

I'm trying to expand my knowledge of Go's function pointers, and I have a question about what is and is not possible with passing functions as parameters in Go.

Let's say that I want to write a `decorator()` function that can wrap any existing function. For simplicity, let's limit this to functions that accept exactly one parameter and return exactly one value.

If I write a decorator that accepts `func(interface{}) interface{}` as it's argument, it will implicitly work as long as that function I pass in also accepts/returns an `interface{}` type (see `funcA`).

My question is--is there a way to convert an existing function of type `func(string) string` to a type of `func(interface{}) interface{}` so that it can also be passed into a decorator function without just wrapping it in a new anonymous function (see `funcB`)?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func decorate(inner func(interface{}) interface{}, args interface{}) interface {} {
    fmt.Println("Before inner")
    result := inner(args)
    fmt.Println("After inner")
    return result
}

func funcA(arg interface{}) interface{} {
    fmt.Print("Inside A, with arg: ")
    fmt.Println(arg)
    return "This is A's return value"
}

func funcB(arg string) string {
    fmt.Print("Inside B, with arg: ")
    fmt.Println(arg)
    return "This is B's return value"
}

func main() {
    
    // This one works. Output is:
    //
    //   Before inner
    //   Inside A, with arg: (This is A's argument)
    //   After inner
    //   This is A's return value
    //
    fmt.Println(decorate(funcA, "(This is A's argument)"))
    
    // This doesn't work. But can it?
    //fmt.Println(decorate(funcB, "(This is B's argument)"))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. One reason for that is the mechanics of passing parameters differ from function to function, and using an `interface{}` arg does not mean "accept anything". For example, a function taking a struct as an arg will receive each member of that struct, but a function taking an interface{} containing that struct will receive two words, one containing the type of the struct, and the other containing a pointer to it.

So, without using generics, the only way to implement this is by using an adapter function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [reflect package](https://godoc.org/reflect) to handle functions with arbitrary argument and result types.

```
func decorate(inner interface{}, args interface{}) interface{} {
    fmt.Println("Before inner")
    result := reflect.ValueOf(inner).Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(args)})
    fmt.Println("After inner")
    return result[0].Interface()
}
```

[Run the code on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/9Jh1rSsjzHV).

Like the `decorate` function in the question, the function in this answer assumes one argument and one result. The function must be modified to handle other function types.

The OP should consider the tradeoffs  between the anonymous wrapper function proposed in the question and the use of the reflect package here. Calling the function through the reflect API is slower than calling the function through the anonymous wrapper.  There's also a loss of type safety with the reflect API.  The anonymous wrapper function adds verbosity.

Comment: I'm impressed. Accepting the function as an interface never occurred to me as an option. Now whether it is wise to actually do this in production is another matter entirely, but I love the outside-the-box thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

For the record, with Go 1.18 and the introduction of generics, the `decorator` function becomes almost trivial.

You may declare a type constraint as such:

```
type UnaryFunc[T any] interface {
    func(T) T
}
```

The constraint itself is parametrized with `T` to allow for unary functions that take and return arbitrary types.

In the `decorate` function you then instantiate the constraint with a type parameter. The signature becomes:

```
decorate[T any, F UnaryFunc[T]](inner F, arg T) T
```

Thanks to type inference, you can just pass concrete arguments to the function, and both `T` and `F` will be unambiguous.

Example alternatives without a named constraint:

```
// accept and return T
decorate[T any](inner func(T) T, arg T) T

// only return T
decorate[T any](inner func() T) T

// return T and error
decorate[T any](inner func(T) (T, error), arg T) (T, error)

// N-ary function
decorate[T, U any](inner func(T, U) (T, error), argt T, argu U) (T, error)
```

The obvious limitation is that the interface constraint `UnaryFunc` specifies only functions that take and return exactly one arg of type `T`. You can't do otherwise, because the type set of an interface constraint may include types which support the same operations — and calling with one arg is not compatible with calling with N args.

The full program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type UnaryFunc[T any] interface {
    func(T) T
}

func decorate[T any, F UnaryFunc[T]](inner F, arg T) T {
    fmt.Println("before inner")
    result := inner(arg)
    fmt.Println("after inner")
    return result
}

func funcA(arg int) int {
    fmt.Println("inside A with:", arg)
    return arg
}

func funcB(arg string) string {
    fmt.Println("inside B with:", arg)
    return arg
}

func main() {
    // this works
    decorate(funcA, 200)
    
    // this also works
    decorate(funcB, "Func B")
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/3q01NiiWsve

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to convert an existing function of type func(string) string to a type of func(interface{}) interface{} so that it can also be passed into a decorator function without just wrapping it in a new anonymous function (see funcB)?

No. It's that simple: No.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond, but I consider details to be more important than the answer. If someone asked me the same question 1 year from now, I don't want the conversation to be, "Can you do it? No. Why? Because Volker said so."

Comment: @riwalk Then you should try to be more specific in your question. It's not so easy to know how much details to give, or what details would be relevant to you.